# Display multiple images on slider from database

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

How to create a image slider which displays multiple images from database.
Using express.js
ex. [have a look at the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guPBt.jpg)

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: The easiest and simple way to build slider.                                                                      

                                                                                                                   
`Demo :` https://jsfiddle.net/whitehack/dceagw6y/14/

`Reference :` http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/demos/lazyLoad.html